# Prevent iOS from turning double hyphen into 'en-dash' in React Native TextInput

Tags: react-native

I'm making a Morse Code translator app with React Native, but whenever a user types '--' into the InputText, it automatically corrects (on iOS at least) to '–' (en-dash), which is not desirable, for it makes the morse code unreadable.

I've done my best to search the internet, but to no avail. I also attempted using different monospace fonts, but it appears not to make a difference.

I would like to somehow, using React Native stop the double hyphen from being automatically being turned into the en-dash, for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `keyboardType` to `ascii-capable` you can achieve the desired.

Please note that the `ascii-capable` is a ios only option.

```
<TextInput 
  style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
  value={this.state.text}
  keyboardType={'ascii-capable'}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
/>
```

Here is the different type of [keyboard](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#keyboardtype)

The end result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It helped me. I was comparing string with hyphen. But sometimes because of double hyphen i could no do it. I changed my key oard type to Ascii and then i could detect hyphen.

Comment: How to stop entering hyphens in react native TextInput.i was using regex and replace but flicker happened. When I enter and check if enter value hyphen then replace with ' '.i want same as Google pay and phone pe after the QR scan amount enter input.